# PHP use {{name}} to echo in HTML

Tags: php, html

I have seen in some scripts, where they use {{}} to echo inside HTML, and I think it looks way more clean!

So, for example I now have:

```
<?php $hi = "hello"; ?>
<html>
<title><?php echo $hi; ?></title>
```

and that will display hello in the title, but what I would like to have is:

```
<?php $hi = "hello"; ?>
<html>
<title>{{hi}}</title>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This means you need a templating engine like "twig", "blade", "smarty" or you can use a combination of regex and output buffering to create that by yourself.

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/Level-2/Transphporm for an even cleaner solution (no, I'm not affiliated to the project).

Comment: @Jacco Interesting project you linked.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, you cannot get the variable name (unless using unreliable hacky methods). But as @samayo mentioned, this is usually handled by a template engine.

If you want to mange this yourself, you can do the following:

```
$array = [
  'tag' => 'a',
  'text' => 'b'
];

$html = '<html>
 {{tag}}
 <body>
  {{text}}
 </body>
</html>';
```

Now you can use a couple of methods to replace this, usually done by regex:

```
preg_match_all("/.*({{(.*)}})/", $html, $result);
```

Outputting:

```
$result = array(
  0 =>  array(
    0   =>  '{{tag}}'
    1   =>  '{{text}}'
  )

  1 =>  array(
    0   =>  '{{tag}}'
    1   =>  '{{text}}'
  )

  2 =>  array(
    0   =>  'tag'
    1   =>  'text'
  )
)
```

You could also directly replace the data with [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

With this, you have all the data you would need to replace text.
`$result[2][0]` is referring to `$array[key]` (`$array[$result[2][0]]`))replacement definition. 
This is how template engines usually work.

Comment: Hi, the problem with this is is that the whole html is still in the $html tag, I would like to have it without having the html in a tag that I still need to echo

Comment: Then buffer the data using [these](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) functions and replace the text at the end of the script when everything is loaded into the buffer, fetching it and replace as described in the method above. (`$html = ob_get_contents()`)

Answer (score 1):

What you have probably seen it was a template engine, have a look at twig here : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Here's the documentation:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation

Here's how you can install it :
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/intro.html#installation

Or AngularJS:

Here's a link: https://angularjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Dust.js] (www.dustjs.com) successfully like templating javascript engine in my PHP project. Dustjs is good framework mainly if you need some resources from REST sources using JSON.
DustJs is designed to run asynchronously on both the server and the client browser. At this time is have choosed the last option.
DustJs can use Partials - Templates that can include other templates.

Dustjs has ability to navigate onto your JSON structure looping and searching KEYS to get data simplifying your rendering work and uncoupling your data of user interface.

DustJs is maintained by Linkedin Team and largely adopted on mainly site.

Give a try to him. Start on http://www.dustjs.com/guides/getting-started/.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

use php frameworks that has a template engine
like laravel ( Blade templating engine )

[https://laravel.com](https://laravel.com/)